# Bootstrap modal + carousel. Next and prev slides doesn't appear with transition via Javascript

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, carousel

I use boostrap carousel inside of a modal window.

Code of that looks like this:

```
<div id="modal-window-slideshow" data-backdrop="static" class="modal-huge hide fade">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3>Slides</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-huge-body">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
      <!-- Carousel items -->
      <div id="div-carousel-items" class="carousel-inner">

      <!-- Carousel nav -->
      <a href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev" class="carousel-control left">‹</a>
      <a href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next" class="carousel-control right">›</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When user clicks next and prev buttons everything works fine. But i also want to allow user to navigate via left and right arrows on keyboard. I wrote code which does it, but i met strange problem: transitions animation in this case doesn't work. Can i enable that?

**My script**

```
$(document).keypress(function(event) {
  var LEFT_ARROW = 39; var RIGHT_ARROW = 37;

  if (typeof event !== 'undefined' && $('#modal-window-slideshow').is(':visible')) {
    if (event.keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW) {
      $(this).carousel('next');
    }

    if (event.keyCode === LEFT_ARROW) {
      $(this).carousel('prev');
    }
  }
  return true;
});
```

Comment: keyCode 39 is right arrow. 37 is left. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243025(v=vs.60).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, i found the workaround. I just seek necessary links and then click it.

```
$(document).keypress(function(event) {
    var LEFT_ARROW = 39; var RIGHT_ARROW = 37;

    if (event.keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW) {
      $('a.carousel-control.right').trigger('click');
    }

    if (event.keyCode === LEFT_ARROW) {
      $('a.carousel-control.left').trigger('click');
    }
   ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).bind('keyup', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode==39){
     //keycode for right arrow 
    }   
    else if(e.keyCode==37){
    // keycode for left arrow 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this code, for next, and previous page, combinating it with an id called next and previous

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {

            if (e.keyCode == 39) {  
                window.location.href = $("#next").attr('href');
            }
            if(e.keyCode==37){
                window.location.href = $("#previous").attr('href');
            }});
```

So, if you have an element in your html page, or php page with this id the function works specifically with that id.

Example:

```
<div class="buttons">
<a href="www.urlpage.tld/previous/" class="prev" id="previous" title="Previous Page"></a> <a href="www.urlpage.tld/next/" class="next" id="next" title="Next Page"></a>
</div>
```

I hope this help you.

Regards!